# CSP Error: Endpoint Not Permitted Even Though Referenced in Policy?

Tags: node.js, content-security-policy, react-helmet

I'm getting this CSP error:

> Refused to connect to 'https://cdn.userway.org/remediations/consolidated/123451234/s2345234g5.json' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' [https://cdn.userway.org/*"](https://cdn.userway.org/*%22).

I was expecting `https://cdn.userway.org/*` in the policy, to permit `https://cdn.userway.org/remediations/consolidated/123451234/s2345234g5.json`.

What's the correct way to edit the policy so as to avoid this error?

Comment: What makes you think that's a CORS error? Looks more like [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to me

Comment: You're 100% Phil -- I thought CORS and Content Security Policy were two references to the same thing. I even tagged the post with a CSP tag. I'll update the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `connect-src 'self' https://cdn.userway.org/*` to the `connect-src 'self' https://cdn.userway.org`. CSP does **not allow** using `*` in the path-part (trailing slash is optional).

In most web-templates the wildcard `*' is interpreted very broadly, for example in Cordova:

```
<allow-navigation href="*://*.example.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

so this often leads to confusion in the CSP.

Comment: Thanks! So if I have this in a policy: `        "https://progressier.com/",
"https://progressier.com/client/script.js",` is that redundant and I only need the first one?

Comment: You need only first one. In CSP implicit `*` is used: "progressier.com" covers any nested paths and filenames ("progressier.com/dir/", "progressier.com/sub/filename.js", etc). "progressier.com/path/" (the trailing slash means folder) cover this dir and any nested subdirs/filenames ("progressier.com/path/subpath/", "progressier.com/path/filename.js", etc). Sources with a path (and the exact file name) are usually used in case of public CDNs of the type `cdnjs.com/boostrap/` so that in the case of XSS, an attacker could not load insecure jquery from `cdnjs.com/jquery/`.

Comment: But "progressier.com" covers standard port numbers only (80 and 443 in this case). You have to specify port number if non-standard ones is used: "progressier.com:8000" or "progressier.com:8000/path/" or "progressier.com:*/path/", etc.